# Unity virtual reality weapon switch (VRTK)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, vrtk

I currently have a game with 2 weapons, instead of running around and picking up the weapons, I would like the player to be able to switch between them.

I have a basic weapon selector script:

```
public VRTK.VRTK_ObjectAutoGrab autoGrab;
 public VRTK.VRTK_ControllerEvents controllerEvents;
 public VRTK.VRTK_InteractableObject[] weapons;

 public int selectedWeapon = 0;

 void Start () {


     SelectWeapon();
 }

 void Update () {

     int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;

     if(controllerEvents.gripClicked)
     {
         if(selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
         {
             selectedWeapon = 0;
         }
         selectedWeapon++;
     }

     if(previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon)
     {
         SelectWeapon();
     }

 }

 void SelectWeapon()
 {
     int i = 0;

     foreach(Transform weapon in transform)
     {

         if(i == selectedWeapon)
         {
             //autoGrab.objectToGrab = weapons[i];
             weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);

         }
         else
         {
             weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         }

         i++;
     }
 }
```

In this script I am trying to use the grip buttons to change the weapons by changing the autograb objecttograb(changing the weapon). I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this or if this is possible, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Currently I can't get it to switch weapons this way, so was wondering if anyone has come up with any solutions

Comment: What have you done to try and debug it yourself?

Comment: From the script, i've tried to change the objectToGrab with the current weapon. I know that the input is working on my Vive controller as i've done a debug log on it when pressed and that both of my weapons work as separate intractable objects. I've tried parenting a 'weapons holder' to the player, even tried to disable/enable different intractable scripts at runtime by setting them as unactive i'm still having no joy!

Comment: You're not digging deep enough. Is `SelectWeapon()` called? What value does `selectedWeapon` have? Does `weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);` execute? You can't stop at "I know the input works," you have to figure out what line *isn't* working. THEN you have a question that can be answered.